# Error: Cannot compare NAT with datetime.date objetc

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Al ejecutar esta línea de código:

```
df2.loc[df2.apply](lambda x: (x['TIPO'] == 'EXTERNO') & (fix_fec(x['FECHAEXP']) date.today()) & (x['DESHABILITADO'] == 1), axis=1), 'OBS'] = 'CONFORME'
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Cannot compare Nat with datetime.date object

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).